# Image uploaded in my folder without extension with node js and multer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, multer

I have a weird problem with node and multer.

My script to upload an image is working, but the images are being uploaded without the extension (jpeg, png, etc).
Just like that:
4a8a1400d04b5ccdfdb829aa5ee62763

If I add an extension (jpeg) to the image, then it's displayed.

My code is like that:

```js
    const multer  = require('multer');

    var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname +'/uploads/' });

    app.post('/test.html', upload.single('avatar'),function (req,res,next){
        
       console.log("minetype"+req.file.mimetype);
       res.render('test', {})       
    });
```

And my form:

```html
    <form action="/test.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="monForm">
       <input type="file" name="avatar" />        
       <input type="submit" value="Upload">       
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can configure filename with this for exemple :
which will preserve the original extension and still generate a random name using uniqid package. (feel free to replace it with something else if needed)

```
const uniqid = require('uniqid');
const path = require('path');
const multer  = require('multer');

let upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, `${__dirname}/uploads/`);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, uniqid() + path.extname(file.originalname));
        },
    }),
});
```

Comment: Your are a master :) your code is working fine :) 
But how can I do for the name of my images was 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 
It's to do a JavaScript gallery on the client side 
Thanks

Comment: you want to keep the original name if the file ? replace cb(null, uniqid() + path.extname(file.originalname)); with cb(null, file.originalname); but if people send you bad filenames you may have isssues

Comment: can you validate my answer if it helped you please ?